# inherited poorly designed databases, adjust to new style guide or maintain old one?

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I'm working on systems that the company will be using for a decade. I will be working on these systems for a long time. I have multiple databases I've inherited that will require most stored procedures to be rewritten or modified (inefficiency and poorly written). The old databases use a lot of style decisions I wouldn't personally use such as prefixing all tables with tbl, all procedures with stpWebGetProcedureName, all fields are pre-fixed with fld and all primary keys are just called fldid etc.

So my question is, if I'm creating new databases, do I continue with their style? And if I'm heavily modifying the old databases, do I also just maintain their style? For a decade?

When is it a good idea to implement a new style guide on existing databases, considering it will take quite a lot of time to convert them to a different style? Or is it okay to have two styles amongst the databases?

Additional info : each database has about 40 tables and 100 stored procedures

Development team is two people.

Comment: If the existing style is documented, you should definitely keep it.  One benefit of a consistent style is that when someone new comes in, they are not stuck dealing with *n* precedessors' different styles.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There's no documentation, but the style is consistent throughout those databases.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff re keeping the existing consistent style. I have had to deal with multiple legacy styles jammed into commercial solutions and it is nightmarish. You don't have to like the style. If the current style isn't documented consider getting it documented.

Answer (score 1):

It is dependant on exactly you wish to use the data for in my opinion.

Should you wish to view the data and report/display data across your company it may well be worth considering a data mart/data warehouse configuration. This will be all separate and would allow you to make more sense and write more easily followed procedures.

If you are doing upgrades on your systems (if they are not bespoke) it would be worth speaking to your supplier to check if there is a direct link to processes.

Moving away from anything which has been there for a large amount of time comes with a risk and so i agree with the guys above. If your heart is set on change it sounds like there you will have a large project on your hands with plenty of out of hours work to sink your teeth into.

Hope this helps a little.